# Displaying Results from Prepared Statements

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following table:

```
| id | name  | age |
|----|-------|-----|
| 1  | Peter | 23  |
| 2  | Amie  | 34  |
| 3  | Eddy  | 45  |
| 4  | Peter | 56  |
| 5  | Eddy  | 67  |
```

I now want to retrieve the age of all users with the name `Peter`.

**JS:**

```
function getAge() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "backend.php",
        data : {
            q : "user",
            name : 'Peter'
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.length > 0) {

            } else {
                console.log("empty")
            }
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(status, error);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset ( $_POST )) {
   if ($_POST ['q'] == "user") {
        $name = $_POST ["name"];

        $stmt = $link->prepare ( "SELECT age FROM tab1 WHERE name= ?" );

        $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $name );
        $stmt->execute ();
        $stmt->store_result ();

        if ($stmt->num_rows >= 1) {
            echo "Yes"; // only this Yes is being returned
            $arr = array ();
            while ( $stmt->fetch () ) {
                $arr [] = $name;
            }
            return $arr;
        } else {
            echo "0 records found";
        }

        $link->close ();
}
```

Instead of an array with `23` and `56`, I only get a `Yes`.

So how can I get the array with the ages?

Comment: you need to `echo $arr;` instead of `return $arr;`, because you use ajax

Comment: You echo the contents of `$arr` in a format that you define (perhaps using json, but this is really up to you) and in the js script you process the received data and display in the way you want it.

Comment: `echo json_encode($arr);` instead of `return $arr;` would work I think (assuming you want JSON returned to the browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this into your php function. this means you want to return json into this page

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

change your return $arr to echo json_encode($arr); to convert your array into a json object also remove your echo "Yes";

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

your php function will look like this

```
if (isset ( $_POST )) {
   if ($_POST ['q'] == "user") {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $name = $_POST ["name"];

        $stmt = $link->prepare ( "SELECT age FROM tab1 WHERE name= ?" );

        $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $name );
        $stmt->execute ();
        $stmt->store_result ();

        if ($stmt->num_rows >= 1) {
            $arr = array ();
            while ( $stmt->fetch () ) {
                $arr [] = $name;
            }
            echo json_encode($arr);
        } else {
            echo "0 records found";
        }

        $link->close ();
    }
}
```